# Read all paragraphs under headings in word document and export it to excel in c# windows

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

The below code reads the paragraph under each heading in a word document untill a carriage return is reached. Am not able to read the paragraphs after carriage return but still under the same heading. Is there a way to accomplish this. Can any1 tell me if its feasible.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph in Doc.Paragraphs)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style style = 
        paragraph.get_Style() as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Style;
    string styleName = style.NameLocal;
    string text = paragraph.Range.Text.Trim();
    string[] words = text.Split('.');

    if (styleName.Contains("Heading") 
        || styleName.Contains("Heading1") 
        || styleName.Contains("Heading2") 
        || styleName.Contains("Heading3"))
    {
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if(paragraph.Next() !=null)
            {
                int j = 1;
                string data = paragraph.Next().Range.Text.ToString().Trim();
                // string h = paragraph.Next().Range.Tables.ToString().Trim();
                string[] dataf = data.Split('.');
                foreach (string dat in dataf)
                {
                    paracount.Add(word + j, dat);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What would happen to text of other styles, say style "Normal" which I'd expect to follow the headings?

Comment: Am reading text following the heading as paragraph. If style is normal it goes out of the loop. If style is heading , it gets all paragraphs under heading until a new line or escape character is encountered.

Comment: how do i read normal style text under heading?

Comment: I know this can be done via access to XML as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686712%28v=office.14%29.aspx but I am not sure how it is done via Interop.

Comment: think its not feasible. even am not finding any way to continue with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //This will return you headers and text below of corrousponding header
   private List<Tuple<string, string>> GetPlainTextByHeaderFromWordDoc(string docname)
{
    #region for Plain text collection from document
    List<Tuple<string, string>> docPlainTextWithHeaderList = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    string headerText = string.Empty;
    string finalTextBelowHeader = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        Document doc = ReadMsWord(docname, objCommonVariables);

        if (doc.Paragraphs.Count > 0)
        {
            //heading with 1st paragraph
            foreach (Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
            {
                Style style = paragraph.get_Style() as Style;
                headerText = string.Empty;
                finalTextBelowHeader = string.Empty;

                if (style.NameLocal == "Heading 1")
                {
                headerText = paragraph.Range.Text.TrimStart().TrimEnd();

                    //reading 1st paragraph of each section
                    for (int i = 0; i < doc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (paragraph.Next(i) != null)
                        {
                            Style yle = paragraph.Next(i).get_Style() as Style;
                            if (yle.NameLocal != "Heading 1")
                            {
                                finalTextBelowHeader += paragraph.Next(i).Range.Text.ToString();
                            }
                            else if (yle.NameLocal == "Heading 1" && !headerText.Contains(paragraph.Next(i).Range.Text.ToString()))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    string header = Regex.Replace(headerText, "[^a-zA-Z\\s]", string.Empty).TrimStart().TrimEnd();
                    string belowText = Regex.Replace(finalTextBelowHeader, @"\s+", String.Empty);
                    belowText = belowText.Trim().Replace("\a", string.Empty);

                    docPlainTextWithHeaderList.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(header, belowText));

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
         //error msg: unable to read
        }

        doc.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}

   //This will read and return word document
   private Document ReadMsWord(string docName)
    {
   Document docs = new Document();
   try
   {
    // variable to store file path
    string FilePath = @"C:\Kaustubh_Tupe\WordRepository/docName.docx";
    // create word application
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    // create object of missing value
    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    // create object of selected file path
    object path = FilePath;
    // set file path mode
    object readOnly = false;
    // open Destination                
    docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly,
        ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
        ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

    //select whole data from active window Destination
    docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
    // handover the data to cllipboard
    docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
    // clipboard create reference of idataobject interface which transfer the data
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
return docs;
```

}